# How to get the mouse position while dragging. Setstate not updating from addEventListener?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal: making a custom knob.

I'm trying to build a custom knob that when I click it, and drag it up/down, will increase/decrease in value until the 'mouseup' event and then stay at it's current value.

Currently I'm using an eventlistener for the 'mousemove' action, which works like it should, but the component doesn't update until the 'mouseup' event takes place within the component. What I'm trying to achieve is constant updates as long as you hold the mouse, and updating the moment you release the mouse, even is that's out of the component. I may making some mistake with the timing of setState within an eventlistener, eventlisteners are quite new to me.

My current code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function ClickDrag({}) {
    const valueFromMouseDelta = ({x, y}) => x + y; // <- calculate the value from x,y location

    const [value, updateValue] = useState(0);
    const [startLocation, updateStartLocation] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
    const [relativeLocation, updateRelativeLocation] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});

    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
        updateStartLocation({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY});
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleDrag);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleDrag);
        });
    };

    const handleDrag = (e) => {
        updateRelativeLocation({x: e.clientX - startLocation.x, y: startLocation.y - e.clientY}); // <- get the relative location
        updateValue(value + valueFromMouseDelta(relativeLocation));                               // <- the actual update I want to happen with every move, which doesn't happen
        console.log(value, {x: e.clientX - startLocation.x, y: startLocation.y - e.clientY});     // <- the value stays 0 while the x,y location does update nicely
    };

    return (
        <div style={{margin: 10}} onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
            {value}
        </div>);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a ref instead of state for these extremely fast events.
state setter returned from useState hook is kind of async and you cannot expect that change imeediately. Though there is way to achieve that by passing a call back to the state setter, ref will be a good candidate for this scenario

Comment: Took me a while to fully figure this out (the react docs tell you you can't use a ref inside a functional component, but explains how to do it later anyways), but it's a full solution to my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CodeBuggy said, I needed to use a ref value instead of the state. In my case, with a functional component, that meant the `useRef()` hook. To make this transition as easy as possible, I wrote this hook around it:

```
import {useRef} from "react";

export function useRefSet(initialState) {
    const ref = useRef(initialState);
    const setRef = newValue =>
        ref.current = newValue;
    const getRef = () =>
        ref.current;
    return [getRef, setRef]
}
```

The downside is that the `ref` can't be passed to other components this way. For my purposes this is fine, and working with a get and set method is more intuitive to me than a ref where you need to get/set the current value by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your handle drag with this version and see if it updates:

```js
const handleDrag = (e) => {
    const newRelativeLocation = {x: e.clientX - startLocation.x, y: startLocation.y - e.clientY}
    updateRelativeLocation(newRelativeLocation); 
    updateValue(value + valueFromMouseDelta(newRelativeLocation)); // <- update the relative location with newRelativeLocation not relativeLocation 
};
```

The reason its "not" updating is because the `relativeLocation` scoped in `handleDrag` is still the old `relativeLocation` used when you added the function into the event listener.

In other words, `value` *is* updating but the `relativeLocation` that you are using when calculating the updated value that is scoped in `handleDrag` is still the old value, so there is nothing being changed.  Calling `updateRelativeLocation` doesn't immediately set the value of `relativeLocation`.  That would be mutating its value if it did.  The `relativeLocation` inside `handleDrag` will only be updated the next time the component is rendered.  What we're doing instead is using the value that will be the next `relativeLocation` and using that to calculate the new value.

Comment: Sadly this didn't help as the new state with the updateValue didn't cause rerenders before clicking the item again.

Comment: Thanks for this idea though, it definitely made my code a bit cleaner with one state (or ref in the end) less!

Comment: @Michiel Ok, I see.  I saw the problem and thought it was the cause.